# Devexpress TabHeader Disappears

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have created ribbon form (XtraMain)and I set IsMdiContainer Property to true,i also add documentManager controle i set MdiParent to XtraMain I have add this code to open child forms

```
public void ViewChildForm(XtraForm _form)
    {
        if (!IsFormActived(_form))
        {
            _form.MdiParent = this;
            _form.Show();
        }

    }
  private bool IsFormActived(XtraForm form)
    {
        bool IsOpenend = false;
        if (MdiChildren.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in MdiChildren)
            {
                if (form.Name == item.Name)
                {

                    tabbedView1.ActivateDocument(item);
                    IsOpenend = true;
                }

            }
        }
        return IsOpenend;
    }
```

and i use this code in click of button to open the child form

```
        private void bbtnEmployee_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        FrmEmployee frme = new FrmEmployee();
        frme.Name = "FrmEmployee";
        ViewChildForm(frme);
    }
```

my problem start when the form contain a LayoutControl for example i have this code that open on click of button

```
        private void btnBonLivraison_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        LayoutControl lc = new LayoutControl();
        lc.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        LookUpEdit OrderNumber = new LookUpEdit();
        OrderNumber.Properties.TextEditStyle = TextEditStyles.DisableTextEditor;
        OrderNumber.Properties.DataSource = shippProdu.GetOrderNumber();
        OrderNumber.Properties.DisplayMember = "N° Bon de livraison";
        OrderNumber.Properties.ValueMember = "N° Bon de livraison";
        lc.AddItem(Resources.selectOrderNumber, OrderNumber).TextVisible = true;
        lc.Height = 70;
        this.Controls.Add(lc);
        this.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        lc.BestFit();
```

the second I click on a button the tabHeader disappears,what cause this problem?and how can I solve it.before I use documentManager I used XtraTabControl and if i click a button to open LayoutControl and after that try to open another form the focus remaining in the first form even when the form two is already opened and if I want to go to form two I must first click on a tab of the first form and then click on tab of the second form , thanks in advance .
this is my main form 
[image]

and this is when the eader disappears
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If DocumentManager resides within the same form to which you add LayoutControl, it is the expected behavior. DocumentManager places a special documents' host onto the main form and set its Dock property to Fill. That is why it is incorrect to place LayoutControl onto the same form and dock it to form edges.

If you need to show tabbed documents and LayoutControl on the same form simultaneously, do not use the MDI mode. Consider the use of a separate UserControl. Place your DocumentManager there. Then, put this UserControl onto your form. Note that in this case UserControl's Dock property should be set to Top or Bottom since LayoutControl should fill all available area or vice versa.

Comment: I have added images so my question to be clear,any suggestions please

Comment: I see. I am talking about the same behavior. Have you had a chance to try the approach I suggested?

Comment: Please bear with me,the approach that i want to go with is "showing tabbed documents and LayoutControl on the same form simultaneously",now I will break your answer into two parts,the first one "do not use the MDI mode" if I disable this option how it is work .the second part "Consider the use of a separate UserControl",I have add a UserControl with DocumentManager but I cannot figure out how to added to the main ribbon form.this is my first time with a UserControl

Comment: I was able to add UserControle to the main ribbon form but still I cannot use it as tabbedView.

Comment: Your UserControl should contain DocumentManager. Documents should contain special UserControls, not forms. If that is not helpful, I recommend contacting DevExpress support team (https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create) and posting your test project there. I believe that they will help you.

Comment: i appreciate your help very much